# How to add extra node under fos_user symfony2

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I want to add extra node under fos_user in config.yml file.

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Dsa\AdminBundle\Entity\User
```

Comment: If you've had a go at solving it please add some code to the question as it generally helps to attract some useful answers.

Comment: What are you trying to implement with that additional node?

Comment: I want to declare global variable that is accessible in fos EventListener.